# Route [controller.create] is not defined when I've already defined the Resource Controller in my Web.php

Tags: php, laravel, routes

So I'm working with two Resource Controllers (I'm not sure if that's the problem but if it is, please let me know); one of them is StudentController and its URL is "/main". It's working as it should, perfectly. Now I'm creating the 2nd Resource Controller which name is TeacherController, and its URL is "teacher/main" - i.e its files are in the 'teacher' folder. This is my web routes file:

**Web.php**:

```
    Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::resource('/main','StudentController');

Route::get('profile','ProfileController@index')->name('profile');

Route::get('profile/edit','ProfileController@edit')->name('profile/edit');

Route::put('profile/edit/{id}','ProfileController@update')->name('profile.update');

Route::resource('teacher/main','TeacherController');
```

Now when I go to teacher/main - it says that "teacher.main.create" is not defined. That is the route that I've used on my create button i.e

```
{{ link_to_route('teacher.main.create','Add a Teacher','',['class'=>'btn btn-success float-right']) }}
```

And this is the create() function in my Resource Controller:

```
public function create()
{
    return view ('teacher/create');
}
```

From my understanding of Laravel Resource Controllers, I shouldn't have to define each Resource Controller function individually as Laravel should automatically detect each of them since I've already defined `Route::resource('teacher/main','TeacherController');` in my Web Routes. What am I doing wrong here? This is just the first function it's getting, then there are other functions like Edit/Destroy that will also pop-up route errors and I don't want to go through with defining each of them individually. Help is highly appreciated.

Comment: `php artisan route:list` it will show you how your routes are registered, including their names  ... the first argument to `Route::resource` is actually a resource name .. if you have a slash in it, it will put the resource in a group with a prefix, the name is the last part, it does not include the prefix in the name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Route::resource('teacher-main','TeacherController');
```

now you can access

```
teacher-main.index
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use in `group` with `prefix` and `as`

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'teacher','as'=>'teacher.'], function () {
    Route::resource('main','TeacherController');
});
```

Now you can use `teacher.main.create`

```
{{ link_to_route('teacher.main.create','Add a Teacher','',['class'=>'btn btn-success float-right']) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this locally, and seems like you're using wrong name for your resource route. I set the routes exactly as in your example, and this is what I got:

[image]

So if you wanted to use the create route, you'd do it like this:

```
{{ link_to_route('main.create','Add a Teacher','',['class'=>'btn btn-success float-right']) }}
```

On the other hand, if you want to keep the names you wanted, you can set a custom name for each of your resource route, like this:

```
Route::resource('teacher/main', 'TeacherController', [
    'names' => [
        'index' => 'teacher.main.index',
        'create' => 'teacher.main.create',
        // etc...
    ]
]);
```

Hope this helps. Happy coding.